# For accessibility, what is the best solution to eliminate having to use 16 font size over 14 on form fields only?

Tags: mobile, accessibility, wcag

What is the best solution to eliminate having to use 16 font size over 14 on form fields only? To pass WCAG Guidelines, we are looking for a solution to not have 16pt only on form fields and still pass accessibility and the need of autozoom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It sounds like you're asking how to cheat on a test. If someone has trouble reading small text, I don't understand why form fields would suddenly be OK.

Comment: Can you quote the particular guidelines you are having difficulties with?

Comment: Hi, so we are in a situation where everything else passes WCAG but just the form text is set at 14 and there is some sort of autozoom that occurs that we still have to support. the fall back on the design is if we change it to 16 it breaks the design. I've heard there may be a work around accessibility when font size of 14 is used only for the forms but would like to know more about this solution. all other text we have is definitely above 16.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which WCAG guidelines you are following (either WCAG 1.0 or you are using an accessibility testing tool which has not interpreted the rules correctly?), but [WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast) explicitly says this about font size:

> **1.4.4 Resize text**: Except for captions and images of text, ***text can be resized without assistive technology up to 200 percent without loss of
>   content or functionality***. (Level AA)

There are a number of techniques available to meet this guideline, including:

- **G142** Using a technology that has commonly-available user agents that support zoom: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G142.html
- **C28** Specifying the size of text containers using em units:https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C28.html
- **G178** Providing controls on the Web page that allow users to incrementally change the size of all text on the page up to 200 percent: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G178.html
- **G179** Ensuring that there is no loss of content or functionality when the text resizes and text containers do not change their width: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G179.html